# Laravel 5.5 migration fails: Update column datatype string to json

Tags: php, sql, laravel

When I migrate my db I get a error on updating a table column from string to JSON.

The column value is like:

```
{"images":["/vendors/57/horse-16.png"]}
```

I checked if this is a valid JSON and that looks good to me..

My migration file is:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('vendor_horses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->json('image')->change();
    });
}
```

My error in Laravel:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8mb4_  
      unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary' (SQL: ALTER TABLE vendo  
      r_horses CHANGE image image JSON DEFAULT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

I don't know what's wrong, the strings are json correct so why does the update fails?

Comment: Did you install `doctrine/dbal` package?

Comment: yes its in my composer.json

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3295)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dig some issues related to the error in Github and found that **when changing into a JSON field, the collation should be set to an empty string** and this issue will be solved. So you can try by changing the below code:

```
$table->json('image')->change();
```

to

```
$table->json('image')->customSchemaOptions(['collation' => ''])->change();
```

For more details you can check this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25741)

Comment: Looks that does part of the trick! New error about separators?
SQLSTATE[22032]: <<Unknown error>>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comm  
  a or ']' after an array element." at position 14 in value for column '#sql-  
  1d30_5751.image'. (SQL: ALTER TABLE vendor_horses CHANGE image image JSON D  
  EFAULT NULL)

Comment: Are you attempting to insert a JSON array with two objects? Make sure your json is correct i.e if there are two objects it should be separated by a comma

Comment: At this point every entry has only one object. But after changing the datatype to JSON I want to add more objects to it

Comment: So now every column row is like:
{"images":["/images/57/image-16.png"]}
After datatype change to JSON I want to add images like:
{"images":["/images/57/image-16.png","/images/57/image-20.png","/images/57/image-22.png"]}

Comment: So the above error is gone or is it still there? Once your column is in json, you can add all images array as json into the `image` field in your controller.

Comment: After migrate:refresh, importing data again and migrate again, it works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```php
$query = "ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY image JSON DEFAULT NULL";
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement($query);
```

Try this in laravel migration.. working for me